how to calculate the distance of the two points of a rectangle on the x- axis and y =0
I am making some dynamic generation of schematics. And i only need 1 more forumla:
Given Length, Height of a rectangle, and angle of rotation of the rectangle. How can i get the value of x? The center of the rectangle is always the midpoint of X and is always the point of rotation

I tried looking for triangles but it seems im always missing either an angle or a side to be able to do some trigonometry to get x.

What have you tried exactly? Have you tried to find $\frac{x}{2}$ (hypotenuse) by making a triangle with the half length as a side?

@AlainRemillard yes, but that doest create a right triangle so i only have the angle (180-A) and Height/2 (which i would assume be always the longest side). From what i know i dont think i can calculate the remaining sides with only an angle and 1 side of a non right triangle

@AlainRemillard The image above was generated with a 2 by 4 rectangle and rotation Angle = 131.4987 . Is this what you mean Image  i know it says 90 here but its actually rounded off (89.6191). If you sum up the angles its 181.

i need help finding the triangle where x/2 is the hypotenuse.

You should add this image to the post. For the general case, the angle wont be 90 degree. I'll try to draw it later today and add an answer.

$x = L \sin A $

@jjagmath so on a Length=2, Height=4, A= 140. My cad software is showing me that X = 3.1114. But using your formula =2*sin(140) (Im using google sheet as my calculator) i get an answer of 1.960479319 ... Quite far from 3.1114

Sorry, typo. It should be $L / \sin A$.

@jjagmath soo forgot to do the calculations above in radians.. but anyway the correct formula that matched my cad is X = L/sin(180-A)

Which you can simplify because $\sin(180-A) =\sin(A)$

oh my bad i did not see your correction, glad i was able to simplify relatively close to your answer.

There are many ways to draw a right triangle, here is one way to do it.

With what you have, there are many ways to compute de desired value. First, as mentioned by jjagmath, in the comment
$$\frac{x}{2} = \frac{L}{2}\frac{1}{\sin(180-A)}$$
Which can be simplify to
$$x = \frac{L}{\sin A}$$
As you mentionned in the comment, it could also be evaluate with
$$x = 2\sqrt{\left(\frac{L}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{L}{2}\tan (A-90)\right)^2}$$
The last formula is more complicated, but it still work.
No mather what the angle $A$ is, there is always a similar triangle that will allow us to find the value of $x$.

So the formula i got is x = 2 √[(L/2)^2 + ((L/2)(Tan(A-90)))^2] . I a correct? ( going to test it now... )

Definitly something is wrong, so when i tested it out on a Length=2, Height=4, A= 140. Im not getting the the x/2 = 1.5557, that im expecting

I got an answer of x = 2.0726 instead of the x = 3.1114 that my cad software is showing me.

@DrakeJest Not the easiest formula but it should work. When I tried it, I got the $x=3.1114$, same as your software. Jjagmath offered you an easier formula. I'll edit my post to include those two formula.
